# vagrant up eos freezes system completely, not able to bring up eos

Tags: python, vagrant, eos

I am just learning to use the python NAPALM library. The tutorials suggest

> set up a lab using VirtualBox and Vagrant, with a virtual Arista
>   device

I am not able to bring up eos.
I am having the following configuration :

*ubuntu : 16.04 LTS, OS type 32-bit*

*virtual box : Version 5.2.22 r126460 (Qt5.6.1)*

*Vagrant 2.2.1*

*vEOS-lab-4.21.1.1F-virtualbox*

My 
**Vagrantfile**
contents are as follows :

```
VEOS_BOX = "vEOS-lab-4.21.1.1F-virtualbox"
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.gui = true
    end

    config.vm.define "base" do |base|
        base.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
        base.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 12200, id: 'ssh'
        base.vm.network "private_network", virtualbox__intnet: "link_1", ip: "10.0.1.100"
        base.vm.network "private_network", virtualbox__intnet: "link_2", ip: "10.0.2.100"
        base.vm.provision "shell", inline: "apt-get update; apt-get install lldpd -y"
    end

    config.vm.define "eos" do |eos|
        eos.vm.box = VEOS_BOX
        eos.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 12201, id: 'ssh'
        eos.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 443, host: 12443, id: 'https'
        eos.vm.network "private_network", virtualbox__intnet: "link_1", ip: "169.254.1.11", auto_config: false
        eos.vm.network "private_network", virtualbox__intnet: "link_2", ip: "169.254.1.11", auto_config: false
  end
end
```

When I execute `vagrant up`, the system successfully starts the base, starts booting up eos, but finally freezes (is recoverable only through hard reset) after trying to do `EOS initilization`.

Please help. I have tried out lot of things after reading various suggestions on the internet

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you see the system is freezing, you can always turn debug trace to see what is going on, it might be that the system is looping on the same command or really freezing.

```
vagrant up --debug
```

In your case, I believe the issue is with the network, you should associate IP from the [private IP range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) so changing the IP to a private IP will solve your case and you could boot the VM

Comment: I am already running with debug on. But I am new to networking and so I am not able to understand how to implement your suggestion